# Search option for recyclerview with cardviews

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview, firebaseui

I have made an application wherein a `RecyclerView` I show patients name in card view. I am retrieving patients names from database in fire-base. I need to add a search option to my recycler view so that I can search the required card by patients name.

I need help as I have no idea how to do this, plus I can't find any tutorials regarding this. Following is my `CardView` class:

```
public class MedicalData extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView patientdata;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_medical_data);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009688")));
        setTitle("Patient Directory");



        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Patients");

        patientdata = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.patientdata);

        patientdata.setHasFixedSize(true);
        patientdata.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));





    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PatientRequest, DataViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PatientRequest, DataViewHolder>(

                PatientRequest.class,
                R.layout.datatype,
                DataViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {

            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, PatientRequest model, final int position) {

                final String getid = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setName(model.getPatientName());
                viewHolder.setAge(model.getPatientAge());
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MedicalData.this, getid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent int1 = new Intent(MedicalData.this, ShowPatientDetails.class);
                        int1.putExtra("name7", getid);
                        startActivity(int1);
                    }
                });


            }
        };

        patientdata.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;


        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;


        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            TextView pname = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.pname1);
            pname.setText(name);
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            TextView page = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.page1);
            page.setText(age);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you wanne search from Service or Loaded data ?

Comment: from the loaded data (already visible in form of cards)

Answer (score 0):

ok if you wanne to Search from loaded data

what about create your own Recylerview and it`s adapter

let`s say You have Query like this

```
mDatabase.child("TripSummry_CM").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0)
                            {
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    YOURMODEL yourmodel = child.getValue(YOURMODEL.class);
                                    YOURMODELList.add(yourmodel);}
                                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                            }
                     }
```

where **YOURMODELList** is A List 
and

**Adapter** is Your own adapter

and ofcourse you have your own Recyclerview

Now simply you can Search in List of your Object

use this fuction to search

```
public List<Doctor_UI_model>  findDoctors(List<Doctor_UI_model> categories, String name)
{
    List<Doctor_UI_model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Doctor_UI_model cat : categories) //assume categories isn't null.
    {
        if(cat.getName().contains(name))
        //assumes name isn't null.
        {
            models.add(cat);
        }
    }

    return models;
}
```

and in your Search Button Or serchview

```
List<Doctor_UI_model> search_result = findDoctors(Doc_List_Server_All_data, newText);
                        if (search_result.size() != 0) {
                            YourList.clear();
                            YourList.addAll(search_result);
                            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
```

**Attention**

it`s better to keep your Loaded data in list and then added it to another one 
which is used in adapter 
and when you start search in Loaded data list 
clear the other one and add filterd data in it

Comment: so you are saying that i need to first save all the names that i want to display in a list from firebase and then compare it with the objects/cards data. right?

Comment: Right   and search in List Of loadded data

Comment: i already have my recyclerview and adapter should i use those or i need to make a new one?